# How can I change the highlight color of a borderless button?

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton

An ImageButton using the `borderlessButtonStyle` has the holo blue highlight when tapped on it. How can I change the highlight color?

(I know how to change the holo color on regular buttons and image buttons using http://android-holo-colors.com/)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
      android:state_checked="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
      android:state_checked="true"  />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
    android:state_focused="true"></item>

</selector>
```

copy this in drawable folder. And set the item drawables according to you. Then set it as
background for your button in layout xml.

Comment: how to set it in layout.xml?